# Firebase custom action url breaks verification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I hadn't tried to verify any account and changed action URL at firebase authentication for email verification and now when user clicks the action link it doesn't verify the user and there's not a reset button for the action link. i have tried typing its placeholder value but didn't work. anyone know how can i fix this? or do i have to do any additional step to actually verify a user.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
        .then(cred => {
          ref.set({
            username: this.username,
            avatar: this.signAvatar,
            user_id: cred.user.uid,
            villaComments: [],
            ratedVillas: []
          })
        }).then(() => {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
          user.sendEmailVerification();
           } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a typo. when I write the old value it worked.

Comment: I still wonder how would I manage to verify user with a custom action link